# Laravel new -bash: laravel: command not found

Tags: macos, bash, laravel

Being new to Laravel, I am following a couple of tutorials.

I could go through the first one covering the basics almost with no issue, using only the AMP environment built in Mac OSX Mavericks.

I am now moving on to a more complex one to learn how to create an app from A to Z, and this one requires Homestead, that I have been able to install and setup.

If I try to create a Laravel App with the `composer` command, it works just fine.

However, as soon as I try to create an app with the `laravel new` command, I get the following error message:

```
-bash: laravel: command not found
```

I have read many answers to similar questions, but none of these seem to fix my problem, because:

- I do have mcrypt installed
- I tried the `sudo chmod +x
  /usr/local/bin/laravel`to give execute permission to the folder
- and Laravel is working on my computer, since I have already created a
  couple of apps.

So, why can't I use the `larval new` command? Do I need to update/install something else?

I can provide you with additional information/code/logs if necessary.

**[EDIT]: I found the answer to my own question.**
The solution was simply to place the `~/.composer/vendor/bin` directory in the PATH with the following `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`command in Terminal, as explained here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/trying-to-make-use-of-the-laravel-installer .

Comment: Just edited the question explaining why the existing answers to not fully address the problem.

Comment: You read http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#installation , don't you?

Comment: Yes @MarcinNabiałek I did, but did not find any solution to my problem.

Comment: @ThibaudClement you should add an actual answer with your solution so the question is marked as solved

Comment: @AndHeiberg I can't, the question was marked as duplicate, and already points to another answer. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Yeah they really should also mark it as answered then. Really annoying if you're going through answering unanswered questions and they have already been answered. Anyways :)

Comment: @AndHeiberg Agree. Sorry about that, too. Have a nice day.